# Powershell - comparing lines

Tags: powershell

I need to parse through a file and when lines with the same connection-ID (655629, in this example) are found, compare them and only keep the one that is not 'other'

These two lines, for example:

```
08/26-20:26:42.655629  [**] [1:9000003:0] troll [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.0.1:35964 -> 192.168.0.99:368
08/26-20:26:42.655629  [**] [1:1:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.0.1:35964 -> 192.168.0.99:368
```

Someone here was already kind enough to share this code, that basically returns the parts of each line that I need, formatted the way that I need.

```
Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | % {
'|' + (($_.Split()[0, 9, 11, 4] -replace ':', '|') -join '|') + '|' 
} | Out-File "C:\Log\logout.txt"

|08/26-20|26|42.655629|192.168.0.1|35964|192.168.0.99|368|troll|
|08/26-20|26|42.655629|192.168.0.1|35964|192.168.0.99|368|other|
```

However, I only want to keep one line when there are multiple lines with the same connection ID (655629 in this example). In cases when there are multiple lines with the same connection ID, I need the line that is NOT 'other'

I'm showing that first indice [0] only for comparison-sake. I need to remove it from the final output for all lines.

For example, final output should look something like this:

```
|192.168.0.1|35964|192.168.0.99|368|troll|
|192.168.0.254|35964|192.168.0.99|368|troll|
|192.168.0.9|35964|192.168.0.99|368|other|
|192.168.0.199|35964|192.168.0.99|368|troll|
|192.168.0.199|35964|192.168.0.99|368|other|
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend parsing your input with a regular expression and creating custom objects from the submatches rather than just splitting the lines like you're doing now.

```
$re = '^(.*?)\.(\d+)  \S+ \S+ (\S+) \S+ \S+ \S+ (.*?):(\d+) -> (.*?):(\d+)'

Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | Where-Object {
    $_ -match $re
} | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Timestamp    = $matches[1]  #?
        ConnectionID = $matches[2]
        ...
        Source       = $matches[4]
        Destination  = $matches[6]
    }
}
```

That will allow you to actually filter the data by field values:

```
... | Sort-Object ConnectionID -Unique | ...
```

The data can be exported in delimited format via `Export-Csv`:

```
... | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.txt' -NoType -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I am going to rethink my approach and use regex, as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If the last field that you want to remove is always going to be 'other', you could add a where-object filter to remove them.

```
Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | % {
'|' + (($_.Split()[0, 9, 11, 4] -replace ':', '|') -join '|') + '|' 
} | where-object {$_ -notlike "*other|"} | Out-File "C:\Log\logout.txt"
```

If 'other' is representative of something else, you could use a -UNIQUE option and see about filtering to only a single copy of each. Problem being you don't currently name the fields, which you could do via expressions..

```
(Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | select @{name="DateTime";Expression={$_.split(" ")[0].split(".")[0]}}, @{name="ConnectionID";Expression={$_.split(".")[1].split(" ")[0]}}, @{Name="IPAddress";Expression={$_.split()[9]}} | sort-object -unique IPAddress ) -join("|")
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is helpful.